# Select columns from another workbook VBA>> Run time 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to open another workbook, select a column from that workbook and paste it into my active workbook. However i am running into this error

Runtime 1004: Select method of worksheet class failed

Have tried different ways from watching youtube but cant seem to solve the issue, help pls! thanks in advance!

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPCxr.jpg)

Comment: No screenshots of code please, though the answer to your question is that you're trying to select a non active worksheet.

Comment: You can cut out two thirds of your code by removing the use of  `.Activate` and `.Select`. For example, instead of writing `Sheets("Working").Activate` and `Range("D:D").Select` and `Selection.PasteSpecial` you can write `Sheets("Working").Range("D:D").PasteSpecial`. 3 lines turn into 1, and its much more readable!

Comment: And without `.Activate` and `.Select` you won't run into issues like this where you have to keep track of what the `ActiveSheet` or `Selection` objects are currently referring to after each individual line. No more errors because the Selection and active object weren't lined up.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really follow the suggestions to avoid the `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`Activexxx` pattern in favour of using fully qualified Range references

While sticking to your code "style", you have to change:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Working").Select
```

to:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Working").Select
```

because you cannot select a Worksheet in a Workbook which is not the "active" one, since the previous `Workbooks.Open` statement has made the newly opened workbook the "active" one